# Tooltip icon not showing at all using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a tooltip at my code page, I tried adding z-index at the css, but it did not work, i tried change the display to inline-block but still the same.

Here is my code:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
    z-index: 9999999
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tooltip">
         <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
         <span class="tooltiptext">Hello nice to meet u!</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

The following images are what I can see from
[image]

Comment: Could you please write in more detail? nothing is understood.

Comment: Based on the snippet it seems to work fine, you will need to give more code. (it is just hidden on the top below the top of the body

Comment: I did the snippet with the code provided, but based on the printscreen provided, I would more say that the font awesome link is missing as it shows the `i` element with 0x0 size. How do you implement font-awesome in your site?

Comment: @MaxiGui i just put it like this <link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: try with the link in the snippet.

Comment: @MaxiGui hi i have used the link in the snippet and this is what i got i posted at the question

Comment: Now it is showing 14x14 so it means you have a problem with the link anyway. For the rest you will need to provide the code of your table.

Comment: @MaxiGui I am not sure what else I need to put cause all the CSS is predefined and I am just trying to get the icon out

Comment: Try to apply a `position: relative` on table and `position: absolute` on your div as a test. `z-index` won't change anything as it is in table.

Comment: @MaxiGui I have tried what u said but the table is blocking my icon now

Comment: We wont be able to help you more without a working example.

Comment: @MaxiGui I tried to take the whole div outside, just under the <body> tag
The tool tip still looks the same

Comment: Again without more code, I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to work on the positioning, look at my example, i just added position:absolute and top and left property and it looks good to me, you can easily work with the dev-tools element inspector on this when you "force state hover"

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
    z-index: 9999999
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="tooltip">
     <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
     <span class="tooltiptext">Hello nice to meet u!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the snippet with the code provided, but based on the printscreen provided, I would more say that the font awesome link is missing as it show the `i` element with 0x0 size.

Comment: TBH i couldn´t recognize anything in the screen :) but that seems to be a good hint to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Change  `.tooltip .tooltiptext { bottom: 125%; }` .

Snippet:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
    z-index: 9999999
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    /*bottom: 125%;*/
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="tooltip">
     <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
     <span class="tooltiptext">Hello nice to meet u!</span>
</div>
```